# Code for Huffman tree using std::unique_ptr not working

Tags: c++

I'm working on building a Huffman encoder for a homework assignment, and I need to know why my code isn't working. I've asked elsewhere on an earlier version, and got a tip to use std::unique_ptr so that the nodes referenced by my pointers won't be deleted from memory when they're deleted from the vector.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>     // Allows the use of std::cout >> and std::cin <<.
#include <string>       // Allows the use of getline().
#include <fstream>      // Allows the use of file I/O.
#include <utility>      // Allows the use of std::bitset.
#include <vector>       // Allows the use of vectors.
#include <algorithm>    // Allows the use of std::sort().
#include <memory>       // Allows the use of std::unique_ptr.

struct node
{
    char data;
    int frequency;
    std::bitset<1> code;
    node *left;
    node *right;
    bool operator<(const node &temp) const {return frequency < temp.frequency;}
};

std::vector<node> nodeVector;

void getHuffmanData()
{
    std::ifstream inStream;
    int size;
    int tempFrequency;
    char tempData;
    node tempNode;

    inStream.open("huff-source.txt");

    if (inStream.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Failure opening input file.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    inStream >> size;

    while (inStream.peek() != EOF)
    {
        inStream >> tempData;
        inStream >> tempFrequency;
        tempNode.data = tempData;
        tempNode.frequency = tempFrequency;
        nodeVector.push_back(tempNode);
    }
    inStream.close();
}

node buildHuffmanTree()     // Returns the root node, which points to all other nodes.
{
    node tempNode;
    node *x, *y;
    std::unique_ptr<node> a (new node);
    std::unique_ptr<node> b (new node);

    while (!nodeVector.empty())
    {
        std::sort(nodeVector.begin(), nodeVector.end());
        *a = nodeVector.front();
        x = a.release();
        tempNode.left = x;
        nodeVector.erase(nodeVector.begin());
        *b = nodeVector.front();
        y = b.release();
        tempNode.right = y;
        nodeVector.erase(nodeVector.begin());
        tempNode.frequency = x->frequency + y->frequency;
        nodeVector.push_back(tempNode);
        std::sort(nodeVector.begin(), nodeVector.end());
        if (nodeVector.size() == 1) {break;}
    }
    return tempNode;
}


int main()
{
    node test;
    getHuffmanData();
    test = buildHuffmanTree();
    std::cout << "Press 'Enter' to continue...";
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

My sample input file, is as follows:

```
4
a 119
b 20
c 44
d 127
```

Now, the error message I'm getting in Xcode occurs after it runs once through buildHuffmanTree(). It says 'Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)' at the line containing '*a = nodeVector.front();'. How would I go about correcting the loop so that the function can return a proper tree, illustrated like this:

```
   310
  /   \
127   183
 d   /   \
    64   119
   /  \   a
  20   44
   b    c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to write to a dereferenced null pointer.
Let me step through your code to show you the error.

```
node buildHuffmanTree()     // Returns the root node, which points to all other nodes.
{
    node tempNode;
    node *x, *y;
    std::unique_ptr<node> a (new node); // a now points to a node in the heap
    std::unique_ptr<node> b (new node); // b now points to a node in the heap

    while (!nodeVector.empty())
    {
        std::sort(nodeVector.begin(), nodeVector.end());
        *a = nodeVector.front(); // you copy the first node in the vector into the node
                                 // on the heap pointed to by a
        x = a.release();         // x now points to the node on the heap pointed to by a
                                 // a now holds a nullptr and will not delete the node on the heap
        tempNode.left = x;       // tempNode.left now points to the node on the heap
        nodeVector.erase(nodeVector.begin());
        . . .
        tempNode.frequency = x->frequency + y->frequency;
        nodeVector.push_back(tempNode);
        std::sort(nodeVector.begin(), nodeVector.end());
        if (nodeVector.size() == 1) {break;}
    }
    return tempNode;
}
```

Now we go through the while loop again

```
    while (!nodeVector.empty())
    {
        std::sort(nodeVector.begin(), nodeVector.end());
        *a = nodeVector.front(); // a now holds a nullptr, so this is BAD
        . . .
    }
```

I believe you do not fully understand the use of `std::unique_ptr`. 
You probably want a collection of `std::unique_ptr`s to all your `node` objects
to persist throughout your program so you have a unique set of nodes that will not disappear.
To link these nodes into your tree, use regular pointers (or maybe shared).
Unique pointers should be used when the object/code block containing the pointer 
has sole responsibility to delete the allocated memory pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: Well, forgetting about `std::unique_ptr`, is there a simpler way to do what I'm trying to do? I know how the Huffman algorithm is supposed to work, I'm just having a hard time building the tree in C++.

Comment: @Andrew You want to represent a binary tree in c++. There are probably many resources on the web that will show you how to do so. One common way is as you have attempted: nodes with two pointers to child nodes. Anther would be to use a vector or array where the left child of the ith entry is at 2i+1 and the right child is at 2i+2.